# Not printing a full line, just chunks in C?

Tags: c, linked-list

I'm having difficulty adding the input from a file to a struct. I'd like to read in from a text file, specified by path, add each line to a new char* named quote, and add the quote to a struct named Thread, that is initialized with a linked list named table.

When I add a word to table, I'm adding it as itself a linked list. This might be where my difficulty is, but I can't see how to fix it.

The trick is that I can see the entire quote printed out from the char* quote. After I add it to the struct, then try to print it by refering to the struct with `t->quotes[i]->quote`, it prints only  a single word.

```
 Thread* initialize_thread(char* path, Classifier *clf, int size){
   Thread* t = malloc(sizeof(t) * size);
   t->clf = clf;
   FILE *fp = fopen(path, "r");
   t->size = 0;

   char line[300]; /* 300 is an arbitrary length to read in lines from the text file*/
   int count = 0;
   if(fp == NULL){
      perror("Error opening file");
      return NULL;
   }
   if ((t->table = malloc(sizeof(t->table) * size)) == NULL){
    return NULL;
   }
   for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
       t->table[i] = NULL;
   }

   while (fgets(line, 300, fp)){
      char* quote = strdup(line);


      LinkedTest* new = malloc(sizeof(*new));
      new->quote = quote;

      printf("%s\n", new->quote);
      float c = get_score(t->clf, quote);
      new->score = c;
      t->table[count] = new;
      count ++;

      printf("%s\n", new->quote);

   }
   t->size = count;
   return t;
}
```

Header file is here:

```
typedef struct LinkedTest {
    float score;
    char* quote;
    struct LinkedList *next;
} LinkedTest;

typedef struct Thread {
    LinkedTest** table;
    Classifier *clf;
    int size;
} Thread;

Thread* initialize_thread(char* path, Classifier *clf, int size);

void write_quotes(char* path, Thread* t);

#endif /* READ_H*/
```

And `get_score()` is here:

```
float get_score(Classifier* clf, char* fragment){
    int l = strlen(fragment);
    char* grams[l];
    for (int i = 0; i < l; i++){
         grams[i] = NULL;
    }

    // this function makes a call to strtok()
    int set = get_grams(fragment, grams);

    int length = 0;
    float score = 0.0;

    // for every gram, get a score
    for (int i = 0; i < l; i++){
        char* g = grams[i];

        if (g != NULL){
            float num = 1.0;
            float denom = set;
            length++;

            float gp = get_gram_probability(clf->dictionary, g);
            float pp = get_probability_gram_is_positive(clf->dictionary, g);

            // numerator = 1 + prob_gram_positive * class_prob
            float p = clf->class_prob;
            num += (pp * p);

            // denominator = length of the input string + gram_prob
            denom += gp;

            score += num / denom;
        }   
    }

return score / length;
}
```

And here is get_grams(). It takes a grams[] initialized to a given length and a sentence, and populates the grams with words from the sentence.

```
int get_grams(char* sentences, char* grams[]){
    // Is given an empty char* grams, populates it with words from the sentence
    int count = 0;
    char* words = strtok(sentences, " ");
    while (words != NULL){
        grams[count] = words;
        words = strtok(NULL, " ");
        count ++;
    }
    return count;
}
```

Comment: `int s = strlen((line)) - 1;` Why are you subtracting 1? That isn't correct. Because you need a buffer that is `strlen(line)+1` to fit all the characters plus the terminating NUL. At the moment your buffer is only `strlen(line)` in length. And then you only copy `strlen(line)-1` bytes into `quote`. Which means the the last character and the terminating NUL are not copied. Hence `quote` is both an incomplete and invalid C string. You could get rid of all that `malloc` and copying code with a single [strdup](http://linux.die.net/man/3/strdup).

Comment: If I don't subtract one, won't I also carry over the \n? Good point about the ```strdup()``` , I'll give that a try right now.

Comment: Oh, I see. Yes you are correct. That is one way to chomp the newline. (A comment would have helped there). But you still need to NUL terminate `quote` to make it a valid string. And please show `get_score` because we need to know whether it may be corrupting `quote`. Actually, you really should post a [mcve].

Comment: You're right, I always forget that comments are helpful! I've added the strdup(), while it hasn't fixed the problem it certainly looks nicer.

Comment: I'm suspecting you may be using something like `strtok` in `get_score` which will change `quote`.

Comment: So I should pass in a copy to strtok()? That might be exactly the problem.

Comment: Yes, you could make a copy but that may or may not be the best way. You need to show us the code that calls `strtok` so that someone can answer your question more precisely with how your could code be best changed to work. Please also take from this the understanding of why we keep asking for a [mcve].

Comment: Thanks @kaylum, passing in a copy at least solves most of the issue. I'll try to keep to the minimal, complete, verifiable.